# How to fetch text from image properly in android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-camera

How to fetch text from an image properly in android ?

I was **able to fetch text from image using textreact api** but was not able to fetch text properly. If commercial library is fine for me. The image was taken from gallery and even from camera as well but was not to fetch text properly. Please help me out with some examples

Comment: http://roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr/. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for the comments but was looking for Android platform. If you can help me out to find out on android will be really helpful.